# Python non-block reading from a serial port: continuously dump the data to a file

Tags: python, multithreading, serial-port, pyserial

I am sending continuous stream of data from Arduino to my serial port at a high speed. I would like to dump those data to my hard drive continuously.

At low speed, a simple and inefficient code would do:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM4', baudrate=9600)
f = open('data.dat', 'wb')
for i in range(10000):
    data = ser.read()
    f.write(data)
    f.flush()
ser.close()
f.close()
```

At higher speed, we can change `data = ser.read()` to `data = ser.read(10000)` so it would buffer more data in each function call, and therefore more efficient.

However, I am thinking: should there be a better way? Conceptually, I imagine that there is a way to buffer 10000 bytes of data, and in another thread/process to start saving this data to hard drive, and then go back to the main thread/process to keep receiving data.

Would that be reasonable/possible? To be more specific, the questions are:

1) Should I use multiple threads or processes?

2) Where should the data be stored and how should it be passed between threads/processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need. Disk writes are already dispatched. It has to be this way because disk devices don't have a way to write one byte to disk.

Comment: Thank you for your answer David! So just to make sure I understand it correctly, that would mean `file.write()` and `file.flush()` themselves are non-blocking io-operations already?

Comment: @ShawnWang In this case, almost certainly. What would they wait for? Sure you don't think that every time you write one byte to a file, the write operation actually writes a single byte to the disk and waits for the disk to complete the operation.

Comment: Thanks again for answering - and yes you caught me... I did think that way! Sorry about my naive-ness on file operations. That's helpful to know indeed. Thanks again!